# Elixir function calling in a loop with 2 parameters

Tags: elixir, function-call

Is it possible in Elixir to call a function i times with 2 parameters? It would look line this in Java:

```
List myList = new ArrayList();
for(int i=1; i<10; i++) {
   myList.addAll(doSomething(other_list,i))
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a loop in [tag:elixir]. Also you cannot modify anything in place as in java, _everything_ is immutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basing on your Java code, I suppose `doSomething(otherList, i)` returns a list. If so, then you can use `Enum.flat_map` in Elixir, like this:

```
Enum.flat_map(1..9, fn i ->
  do_something(other_list, i)
end)
```

Answer (score 3):

The most straightforward way would be to use [`Enum.map/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#map/2):

```elixir
Enum.map(1..9, fn i -> do_something(other_list, i) end)
```

Or a [`for`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1) comprehension:

```elixir
for i <- 1..9, do: do_something(other_list, i)
```

That being said, it really depends on what `do_something` is doing. Elixir lists are linked lists: if you plan to access the `i`th element inside the "loop", your time complexity will be quadratic. You probably would need to rethink your approach to work on elements rather than the list, [`Enum.with_index/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#with_index/2) should help:

```elixir
other_list
|> Enum.take(10)
|> Enum.with_index(1, &do_something/2)
```

Comment: Also, using `Stream` if the intermediate results are out of interest: `1 |> Stream.iterate(&(&1+1)) |> Stream.map(&IO.inspect(&1, label: "#{&1}")) |> Enum.take(10)`.

Answer (score 1):

In functional programming, you have to treat data differently.  You send the data through, process it, and get the data back.  In Java, you wanted to store each iteration in an outside loop, in Elixir, you just want to interact with the data (process it) and then spit it out.  To do this, you want to use the [Enum.map](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html) approach.  This will return a list of data that each iteration spit out.

For instance:

```
iex(3)> Enum.map(1..9, &(&1 + 1))
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

so for your function

```
defmodule Something do
  def do_something(index) do
    index + 1
  end
end
```

will return this in iex:

```
iex(7)> Enum.map(1..9, fn index ->
...(7)>   Something.do_something(index)
...(7)> end)
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

The major thing here is understanding the difference between Functional and OOP programming.  The major difference is the way data is handled.  Which is explained well [here](https://medium.com/@shaistha24/functional-programming-vs-object-oriented-programming-oop-which-is-better-82172e53a526)